# EXCEL: count combinations for unique values

Tags: excel, combinations

I'm trying to count the following in excel:
I have a number of unique values for X (say 4), each appearing twice (in random order) in the data set. I want to count the number of each combination (regardless of order) of values on a second column Y for each value of X.

Example (here in order):

```
X Y

1 A
1 D
2 A
2 C
3 B
3 C
4 A
4 D
```

As output, I need:

```
n A,D 2
n A,C 1
n B,C 1
n B,D 0
```

(Let's assume all other combinations don't exist.)

Is this possible without rearranging the data? I don't mind putting in 4 formulas (for each possible combination).
My starting point was akin to this: [excel count unique combinations of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613134/excel-count-unique-combinations-of-columns), but I can't quite figure it out and also I know what feels like next to nothing about excel or coding...

Comment: At the output, do you already have the combinations that you want to count? Or do you expect the formulas to enumerate the combinations as well?

Comment: At the output, is A,D the same combination as D,A?

Comment: Only the four combinations of interest are possible; and A,D = D,A.

Answer (score 1):

To get the count of pairs if the data is not in order, first one needs to get the pairs by X.  Create a unique list of X and use this formula:

```
=CHAR(AGGREGATE(15,6,CODE($B$2:$B$9)/($A$2:$A$9=D2),1))&","&CHAR(AGGREGATE(15,6,CODE($B$2:$B$9)/($A$2:$A$9=D2),2))
```

Note this only works if the Y is one character like your data.

[image]

Then create a unique list of that output and use a standard COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(E:E,G2)
```

[image]

Or you can use a pivot table on the first helper columns to get the same without the need of getting the unique pairings.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a helper column, you can combine the data into something you can count. Use the formula `=IF(A2<>A1,B2,C1&","&B2)` in column C. So your data then becomes:

```
X Y 
1 A A
1 D A,D
2 A A
2 C A,C
3 B B
3 C B,C
4 A A
4 D A,D
```

Then it's a matter of counting up the combinations. Here's a snapshot of my example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MMULT function for this purpose, like this (You can insert line breaks with Alt+Enter but you do not have to, it also works if you write it on the same line):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
  --($B$2:$B$19=  LEFT($D2,FIND(",",$D2)-1)  ),
  MMULT(
    --($A$2:$A$19=TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$19)),
    --($B$2:$B$19=  MID($D2,FIND(",",$D2)+1,LEN($D2))  )))
```

You have to enter this as an array formula (After typing, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, instead of just Enter; you will see the formula inside braces, like this: {=...}).

Here is a screenshot to show what the ranges in the formula mean:
[image: Excel screenshot]